# ContentChildren won't load any data when querying RouterLink and RouterLinkWithHref

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a [Structural Directive](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives) that will behave similarly to the [`RouterLinkActive`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive) directive.

So I implemented the [UnlessDirective](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#write-a-structural-directive) example and added the parts from the Angular's [`RouterLinkActive` directive](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/directives/router_link_active.ts) where it obtains the children through the [`ContentChildren`](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren) decorator.

```
// TODO(issue/24571): remove '!'.
@ContentChildren(RouterLink, { descendants: true })
links !: QueryList<RouterLink>;

// TODO(issue/24571): remove '!'.
@ContentChildren(RouterLinkWithHref, { descendants: true })
linksWithHrefs !: QueryList<RouterLinkWithHref>;
```

My template looks like this:

```html
<p *appUnless="false">
    This paragraph is displayed because the condition is false.
    <a routerLink="/another-page">my link</a>
</p>
```

And I tried to access the links with:

```
ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    console.log("links length", this.links.length);
    console.log("linksWithHrefs length", this.linksWithHrefs.length);
}
```

The problem is, the `links` and `linksWithHrefs` variables are never filled with any contents. What am I missing? Full code in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rkkp6z). I'm using Angular 7.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues, one directly related to the implementation of your directive:

1. You arent importing `RouterModule`, and most importantly calling
   `forRoot(...)`, into your root module. For that reason, the anchor
   in your root component template is not bounded to an instance of
   `RouterLinkWithHref` instance.`
2. The fact that your directive is structural does not
   allow you to query for content childs. Here is where the language
   gets kinda tricky, so Ill do some research and Ill update my answer
   later.

For the moment, if you basically refactor your directive to simply by an attribute one as [in this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-segeto?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html), it will work as expected.

Comment: Regarding number 1, I fixed the importing of RouterModule as you suggested, thanks. Regarding number 2, maybe that's a bug? I opened [an issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/28391) at angular github. As for your suggestion, my goal is to conditionally show the container's contents based on the child links, so an attribute directive wouldn't be enough I'm afraid.